# Как сделать эффект матового стекла на динамическом фоне?

Tags: css

Мне необходимо создать эффект матового стекла в выпадающем меню. 
Я смотрел кучу примеров но все они завязаны на том что размывают картинку фона.
А мне необходимо размывать все что находится за этим меню Все дивы и текст размывались.

Я пытался как то адаптировать под свои нужды но получается как то блекло

```
.test2{
background: #3333339e;
width: 250px;
height: 350px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
overflow: hidden; 
 }
 .test2:before {
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.31);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

[image: а]

Нужно что то вроде этого правое изображение
[image: а]

Comment: Скинь пожалуйста html, я тебе сделаю=)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для этих целей [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter). Перед использованием [проверьте поддержку браузерами](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) (WinXP+Chrome49 - полёт нормальный, даже без префиксов). Также, следует учесть, что данное свойство применяется только к прямоугольным областям, что видно при наведении на красный блок.

```css
.text {
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 3px solid #fa0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 8px solid #f30;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  transition: .6s ease;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
.blur:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blur2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 4px solid #0b0;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Мне необходимо создать эффект матового стекла в выпадающем меню. Я смотрел кучу примеров но все они завязаны на том что размывают картинку фона. А мне необходимо размывать все что находится за этим меню Все дивы и текст размывались.</div>
<div class="blur">Красненький</div>
<div class="blur2">Зелёнивенький :)</div>
```

Comment: У меня нет не сафари поэтому у меня он не работает.

Comment: @zeni1agent причём здесь сафари?

Comment: видимо при том, что поддерживается только в сафари и эдже

Comment: у меня гугл 72 тоже не работает...

Comment: @UModeL там вроде написано что поддержка Backdrop Filter только в Safari и Edge  у меня он не работает. http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/02/26/jhk37092d582c58adb3.jpg

Comment: Ребята, я обозначил связку ОС+браузер и она работает. Видимо, включены нужные флаги в настройках. У меня на экране следующая картина - https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7OWN.png

Comment: мы верим что у вас работает :) просто процент поддерживаемости этого фильтра таков, что он пока что не применим в разработке. хотя другого решения этой задачи и нет, наверное.

Comment: В моззиле тоже не рубит

Comment: @teran вот тут я с Вами согласен. Я предложил вариант, с прицелом на будущее.

Comment: @Keeplod Win7 + Chrome72 = http://joxi.ru/L215xkgu8P3Eb2 (на Android 5 + Chrome72 тоже норм) Дело во флаге "Experimental Web Platform Features"

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 похоже, что только в Мозилле нет заветного флажка))

Comment: кто бы и что не говорил в хроме [работает](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjjcz2s39rusgna/2019-02-27_052115.png)

Comment: у меня вот так работает) .blur {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSECBmSX8EBnSNh3SNtjLJ7DofgF9Y8iHeAwXiN_joP49358ZG-xg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: blur(5px);
    float:left;
}
<div class="blur"></div>