# Как сделать эффект прозрачности+размытия фона блока. Эффект "запотевшего стекла"

Tags: javascript, html, css3, blur

Всем привет!

Такая задача: Есть волноэкранный блок с фоновым видео, в нем в середине(от верху и низу одинаковые отступы, сбоков также) есть блок с текстом, мне нужно у этого блока с текстом сделать фон полупрозначный и размытый.

1 - Про css3 вкурсе, но он размывает весь родительский, а мне нужно только фон предка - Эффект "запотевшего стекла". 
2 - Фейк эффект прокатил бы, если бы у родителя был статичный фон, а не видео.

Есть ли варианты?

Всем спасибо!

пример (на фоне видео. у блока с текстом эффект запотевшего стекла):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без примеров кода вам никто помочь не сможет.

Comment: Кода как такого нет, я как раз думаю над реализацией. Сейчас накидаю примерную базу.

Comment: Также неплохо было бы **показать**, что должно получится. *Лучше один раз увидеть, чем сто раз прочитать (с)*.

Comment: *Лучше строчка кода, чем тысяча слов*

Comment: добавил скриншот как пример

Comment: не обращайте внимание на размытие слева самого видео - это камера в видео

Comment: нашел такую штуку https://codepen.io/ariona/pen/geFIK - буду курить

Comment: @DexColt если для динамического фона, то не стоит курить эту штуку, ибо то же, только в профиль. Лучше покурите это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/949607/265406 Пока универсального решения нет на CSS, в основном из-за Мозиллы.

Comment: @UModeL спасибо за совет!